# how to use fuzzy search inside reg expression?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I want to use fuzzy search inside reg expression for example ,

if search term is "Caancer" then fuzzy search will return something like "cancer" then I want to add this into reg expression like /.* cancer. */

I tried something like,

1.search=/.* blasttoma. */~&queryType=full

2.search=/.* blasttoma~. */&queryType=full

but its not giving any results

I'm expecting if I do something like,

search=/.* blasttoma. */~&queryType=full

it will return result,
 "Neuroblastoma"

Comment: Please try formatting your answer with back ticks `like so`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not supported. You could run query terms though the Bing Spell Check API to make sure they are spelled correctly before passing the regular expression: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/spell-check.

Alternatively, you can use the Autocomplete API with fuzzy mode to get candidate terms from the index to use in the regex expression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/autocomplete